# Apex Interactive Reports, Users subscriptions getting deleted

Tags: oracle-apex

We have Oracle Apex 4.0.2 version instances installed in Dev, Test, Prod environments.

We use the same application number across all the 3 environments
eg: App no. 200 is used in all the 3 environments.

When the App from Dev environment is imported to Test environment.
The users subscriptions  for the interactive reports are getting deleted.

Any ideas or suggestions ?

Thnx

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a known feature (or bug, depending on your perspective). I ran into this myself, and managed to solve it with the help of Joel Kallman's excellent [blog post](http://joelkallman.blogspot.in/2010/07/where-did-my-saved-interactive-reports.html).

Comment: I saw that blog where he gives the solution for  problem of losing saved interactive reports when migrating from one application ID to another or across workspaces or instances. In my scenariou i am losing the users subscriptions not the saved reports and i keep my app id (200) same across all apex instances DEV,TEST.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get back the users subscriptions in the target environment with the below procedure.

In my scenario I am moving the app 200 from Dev to Test environment.

1. Export the app 200 from Test environment by selecting Export interactive Report Subscriptions to Yes in Export Preferences tab
2. Extract carefully the wwv_flow_api.create_worksheet_notify code 
   *(you will see more than 1 statements, if there are multiple users subscriptions)*  from the app 200.sql .
3. Extract wwv_flow.g_flow_id and wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset initializer
   statements.

   **Example below:**

   In my scenario I was testing with 1 interactive report users subscription

   ```
   begin
   wwv_flow.g_flow_id := nvl(wwv_flow_application_install.get_application_id,200);
   wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset := nvl(wwv_flow_application_install.get_offset,0);
   wwv_flow_api.create_worksheet_notify (
   p_id => 3351032625694541+wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
   p_flow_id => wwv_flow.g_flow_id,
   p_worksheet_id => 11045125897667191+wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
   p_report_id => 11046318922668871+wwv_flow_api.g_id_offset,
   p_owner => 'abc.def',
   p_email_subject => 'Primary Report test',
   p_email_address => 'abc.def@email.com',
   p_start_date => '2012.09.07.01:00:00',
   p_notify_interval => 'D');
   end;
   ```
4. Import the app 200 from Development environment to Testing
   environment.
5. Execute the above Example pl/sql in  the Test environment, sql prompt.

Run the app in Test environment, You will see the interactive reports users subscriptions to the associated pages.

**Note: This procedure applies only when you have same app id across all the enviornments**